# django is displaying exception as internal server error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In django, is there any way to capture the python script exception and present in the html page, rather than allowing django to provide 500 or page full of exception page(debug=on)

```
try:
    result = my_resolver.query(host,raise_on_no_answer=False)
    for a in result:
        r = r.address
except resolver.NXDOMAIN:
    r = "No record found"
    args = {'message':r}
return render(request, 'dns.html', args)
```

Comment: Maybe this is usefull : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890368/django-catch-exception