# Default general error message in case of any exception in django

Tags: django, error-handling, error-logging

I am developing Restful API using Django.

In case of an error instead of raising python default exception or adding try except on every view,
is there a way to add a default error message which will be returned?

via django settings? via the url's? via a decoretor?

thanx in advanced :)

Oz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global Exception Handling in Django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60426446/global-exception-handling-in-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 1):

Considering you use DRF you can define your own exception handler:

```py
def custom_api_exception_handler(exc, ctx):
    if isinstance(exc, DjangoValidationError):
        exc = exceptions.ValidationError(as_serializer_error(exc))

    if isinstance(exc, Http404):
        exc = exceptions.NotFound()

    if isinstance(exc, PermissionDenied):
        exc = exceptions.PermissionDenied()

    response = exception_handler(exc, ctx)

    # If unexpected error occurs (server error, etc.)
    if response is None:
        if isinstance(exc, YourCustomApplicationError):
            data = {"message": exc.message, "extra": exc.extra}
            return Response(data, status=400)

        return response

    if isinstance(exc.detail, (list, dict)):
        response.data = {"detail": response.data}

    if isinstance(exc, exceptions.ValidationError):
        response.data["message"] = "Validation error"
        response.data["extra"] = {"fields": response.data["detail"]}
    else:
        response.data["message"] = response.data["detail"]
        response.data["extra"] = {}

    del response.data["detail"]

    return response
```

and define your custom exception:

```py
class YourCustomApplicationError(Exception):
  def __init__(self, message, extra=None):
    super().__init__(message)
    
    self.message = message
    self.extra = extra or {}
```

The example above has the following format, however, you can customize it to your needs.

```
    {
        "message": "Error message",
        "extra": {}
    }
```

In order to use your custom exception handler in APIs, in `settings.py` add the custom exception handler to the DRF settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  "EXCEPTION_HANDLER": "path-to-custom-exception-handler.custom_api_exception_handler",
  ... 
}
```

Documentation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling

EDIT: Forgot to mention that you can also use your custom exception in services for validation, etc.

```
if some_condition:
  raise YourCustomApplicationError(msg)
```